# How to create optimizer hints based on explain plan output?

Tags: oracle, optimization, sql-execution-plan

Is there a way to use the explain plan output to generate a full set of optimizer hints for that execution path? Or, more precisely, is there a way to slightly adjust an execution path without writing a full set of hints from scratch?

**Background**
I'm a data analyst trying to learn more about performance tuning for complex sql queries on Oracle (11g). As such I'm getting used to reading explain plans for finding flaws in my query. To fix these flaws I'm limited to adjusting my query, since I don't have the rights to alter indexes on the tables I'm using. One of the things I'm starting to use, and have very little knowledge of, is optimizer hints. When I give a hint to the optimizer to change the execution path (for example, to use a descending order instead of the default ascending) it will literally do just that, discarding things like round robin and buffer sort (or whatever it does) on other parts of the plan. To prevent this I would have to write a full set of hints, and the first place I would look to for this full set of hints would be the explain plan. I'm hoping there's a quick way of slightly altering this plan and telling my query to follow it.

Comment: The optimiser will try to come up with the best plan that incorporates your hint; trying to hint some other behaviour it used to use and had now discarded will likely conflict with that. The more you add hints the more you constrain what it can do and it's easy to make things worse.Hints should be used sparingly, and generally only where you *know* something the optimiser doesn't. Do you have access to Enterprise Manager to run a SQL tuning job?

Comment: @AlexPoole I only have a Toad client, no other tooling. I was reading [this blog](http://www.orafaq.com/node/1798), specifically the part about how an index on (lower_bound, upper_bound) doesn't work well for history tables and wanted to test the performance gain on real data before bothering the dba's with something potentially time consuming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part, once you have generated the plan via an EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT...., you use the following to see a full set of hints that would preserve that plan.

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(null, null, 'OUTLINE'));
```

However if you tweak those hints, you do run the risk of giving it conflicting instructions.